# Statistical significance of difference in percents

Tags: statistical-significance

I'm working with an existing dataset.  It was a small group of children (4) that took a similar test at different points in time while receiving extra tutoring.  What's interesting is how their percentages changed rather than the actual test scores.

I'd like to index the data so the focus is on the change rather than actual percent.  I do have the same data for a control group.

Is there way to calculate if the indexed results are statistically significant?

Comment: Are the percentages just number correct out of total test questions? Are they the same questions each time they take the test?